# while running pdf2docx, I'm getting making page error

Tags: python, pdf

I'm using the below code to convert pdf file to word, some of the pages are giving making page error, I want any workaround to convert those pages with the text inside, ignoring any coloring or images that could make the issue.

```py
from pdf2docx import Converter

def pdf_to_word(pdf_path, word_output_path):
    cv = Converter(pdf_path)
    cv.convert(word_output_path, start=0, end=None)
    cv.close()

if __name__ == "__main__":
    pdf_to_word(pdf_path, word_output_path )
```

I'm getting the below error messages at some pages:

```
[INFO] (1/806) Page 1
[ERROR] Ignore page 1 due to making page error: list index out of range
[INFO] (2/806) Page 2
[INFO] (3/806) Page 3
[INFO] (4/806) Page 4
[ERROR] Ignore page 4 due to making page error: list index out of range
[INFO] (5/806) Page 5
[INFO] (6/806) Page 6
[INFO] (7/806) Page 7
[ERROR] Ignore page 7 due to making page error: list index out of range
[INFO] (8/806) Page 8
[INFO] (9/806) Page 9
[INFO] (10/806) Page 10`
[ERROR] Ignore page 10 due to making page error: list index out of range
```

I tried to convert the pdf to black and white before converting but still the issue is there

Comment: could you provide example of one of the pages where the problem occurred ?

Answer (score 0):

According to this [issue](https://github.com/dothinking/pdf2docx/issues/161), the error may occur because the converter mistakenly parse lines as tables  where a reasonable table structure could not be obtained.

To solve it, deactivate lattice table parsing by setting `parse_lattice_table` to `False` :

```py
def pdf_to_word(pdf_path, word_output_path):
    cv = Converter(pdf_path)
    cv.convert(word_output_path, start=0, end=None, parse_lattice_table=False)
    cv.close()
```